# Registering multiple components against the same matching lifetime scope

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a bunch of components that need to be resolved per matching lifetime scope (InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope).

However, I would have to then specify it for every single one of them, one by one.

e.g.)

```
builder.RegisterType<LukeSkywalker>().As<IJedi>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("starwars");
builder.RegisterType<ObiwanKenobi>().As<IJedi>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("starwars");
builder.RegisterType<MasterYoda>().As<IJedi>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("starwars");
...
```

And you get the picture. Is there a way to specify that "all of these" are InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope?

Something like (pseudo-code):

```
[
    builder.RegisterType<LukeSkywalker>().As<IJedi>(),
    builder.RegisterType<ObiwanKenobi>().As<IJedi>(),
    builder.RegisterType<MasterYoda>().As<IJedi>(),
].InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("starwars");
```

Comment: You want to avoid writing `.InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("starwars")` for each component, but write it *somewhere* only once ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand, I edited the post with an example of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`builder.RegisterType<LukeSkywalker>().As<IJedi>()` return an object of type  `IRegistrationBuilder<out TLimit, out TActivatorData, out TRegistrationStyle>` so you can create your own method for this type.

```
public static class RegistrationsExtensions
{
    public static IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TActivatorData, TStyle> InstancePerStarwars<TLimit, TActivatorData, TStyle>(this IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TActivatorData, TStyle> registration)
    {
        return registration.InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("starwars");
    }
}
```

And call it like this :

```
builder.RegisterType<LukeSkywalker>().As<IJedi>().InstancePerStarwars()
```

You can also create another method that will extend `ContainerBuilder` :

```
public static void InstancePerStarwars<TLimit, TActivatorData, TStyle>(this ContainerBuilder builder, params IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TActivatorData, TStyle>[] registrations)
{
    foreach (IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TActivatorData, TStyle> registration in registrations)
    {
        registration.InstancePerStarwars();
    }
}
```

Then, you will be able to do this :

```
builder.InstancePerStarwars(
    new IRegistrationBuilder<Object, ReflectionActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle>[] {
        builder.RegisterType<LukeSkywalker>().As<IJedi>(),
        builder.RegisterType<ObiwanKenobi>().As<IJedi>(),
        builder.RegisterType<MasterYoda>().As<IJedi>()
    });
```